# At-least-one-in-group-like SQL queries

Tags: sql, group-by, teradata

CLIENTINFO

```
zipcode|id|familyid|lastname|firstname|head
00001|0001|0001|NAME1|PAUL|1
00001|0002|0001|NAME1|JOHANNA|0
00002|0003|0001|NAME1|FRANCIS|0
...
00003|0004|0004|NAME2|PATRICE|1
00003|0005|0004|NAME2|PAULA|0
00003|0006|0004|NAME2|BART|0
...
00004|0007|0007|NAME3|PAT|1
00004|0008|0007|NAME3|JANE|0
00003|0009|0007|NAME3|BURT|0
...
```

Assume a table called CLIENTINFO, which contains
the following columns: zipcode, clientid,
familyid, lastname, firstname and head (whether the
client is head of his/her family, or not). The family 
id corresponds to the id of the family head.

First, how would you translate the following query into SQL 95+:

display families in which at least one member has a zip code
different from those of the other members

For instance, FRANCIS NAME1's zip code differs from PAUL's
and FRANCIS's.

Second, how would you translate into SQL the following statement:

display families in which at least one member has a zip code different
from that of the family head.

For example, BURT NAME3's zip code differs from PAT NAME3's, the family head.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What is your attempt so far?

Comment: Do you want to get all familiy members or just the family id? Btw, Q2 is fully included in Q1 :-)

Comment: @dnoeth, only if there is a family head :-)

Comment: @DavidFaber: Well, *The family id corresponds to the id of the family head*, without head no family :-)

Comment: Ha! Nice, I missed that part

Answer (score 1):

Both questions are exactly the same, when rule #1 is true rule #2 is also true, end vice vers.

To get only the family id, you can use a simple aggregation:

```
select familyid
from CLIENTINFO 
group by familyid
having -- at least two different zipcodes
   min(zipcode) <> max(zipcode)
```

To get all family members, you do the same using *Windowed Aggregates*:

```
select *
from CLIENTINFO 
qualify -- at least two different zipcodes 
   min(zipcode) over (partition by familyid)
<> max(zipcode) over (partition by familyid)
```

Comment: It is not the same, if head and member are seen distinct, meaning the family head is not counted as a member. (but that sounds strange).

Comment: This solution takes it for granted that the zipcode is numeric. What if one of the zipcodes contains letters, e.g., "000A1")?

Comment: It works as well. The `<>` is just a `not equal`and works for characters too. Btw. `!=` doesn't work in Teradata, it has to be `<>` or `not =`

Answer (score 0):

To get families in which someone has a different ZIP code than the family head, you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM clientinfo c1
 WHERE c1.head = 1
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM clientinfo c2
                 WHERE c2.familyid = c1.familyid
                   AND c2.id != c1.id
                   AND c2.zipcode != c1.zipcode );
```

If all families have a "head" then this suffices to answer the first question too; if not then omit the filter on `head`:

```
SELECT * FROM clientinfo c1
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM clientinfo c2
                 WHERE c2.familyid = c1.familyid
                   AND c2.id != c1.id
                   AND c2.zipcode != c1.zipcode );
```